# Why does Chrome's memory saver make Chrome faster?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, memory, performance

I read in Chrome:

[image]

Why does Chrome's memory saver make Chrome faster? I thought it'd only free up some RAM.

Chrome version 108.0.5359.125 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

No, freeing this small amount of memory doesn't make any difference for the
computer's performance. Modern computers measure their memory in
gigabytes, not megabytes.

It may actually make Chrome slower, by losing data that could have been
reused, thus requiring it to be read again from disk.

This is just a stock message. It would have been exactly the same if all
it did was to free up one byte.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Still, 75.4 MB of memory is not very much. And it would be the same "faster" message for one byte or for one gigabyte.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make any difference to the computer's performance.

75.4 MB is way too minimal to have any affect on your computer's performance.

Thus, these 75.4 MB might cause your Chrome to be slowed down due to having to reread data that you freed up.

So the answer is: You shouldn't turn this function on.

Answer (score -1):

Can't speak to the chrome internals, and complexities of memory management, but if you--like many--have 50 to 100 tabs open, and you're low on memory, this 75.4MB adds up to provide resources chrome itself and therefore the tabs you are using.  Just imagine you're using 100% of  your memory, this would be helpful, no?  Conversely, if you have 128GB of RAM then it could probably slow things down by not keeping those tabs memory-resident.